# Object Reference not set to instance of Object in Unit Testing

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

I want to Assert each property of my returned object which has been returned in my controller. Can someone help me with this?

My Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("{id?}")] 
    public IActionResult GetById(string id)
    {
        var customerFromDb = this._custBizManager.GetByID(id);

        if (customerFromDb == null)
        {
            return base.NotFound(); // Status Code 404 - Not Found 
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok(customerFromDb); // Status Code 200 - OK 
        }
    }
```

My Test Method:

```
    [Test] 
    public void GetById_WithExistingCustomer_GetsCustomerById()
    {
        var expectedCustomer = CreatRandomCustomer();

        _customerRepoMock.Setup(x =>x.GetByID(expectedCustomer.Id)).Returns(expectedCustomer);

        var result = _controller.GetById(expectedCustomer.Id);

        var response = (result as Customer);

        Assert.IsInstanceOf<OkObjectResult>(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCustomer.Id, response.Id); ----> ?????? is this right?
    }
```

Comment: Could you post _custBizManager.GetByID pls?

Answer (score 0):

you have null here

```
var response = (result as Customer);
```

since IActionResult is not Customer, especially when it returns base.NotFound();

you can try

```
Customer response=null;
if (result.StatusCode==200) response = (result.Value as Customer);
```

Comment: Yes, I thought the same as well. But Is there any way where is could Assert all the members that I've returned in my return Ok(customerFromDb);

Comment: @RedCloud see my updated answer